# Creating SQL table using dynamic variable name

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I want to create backup SQL tables using variable names.

something along the lines of

```
DECLARE @SQLTable Varchar(20) 
SET @SQLTable = 'SomeTableName' + ' ' + '20100526' 
SELECT * INTO quotename(@SQLTable)
 FROM SomeTableName
```

but i'm getting

> Incorrect syntax near '@SQLTable'.

It's just part of a small script for maintence so i don't have to worry about injections.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
DECLARE @MyTableName sysname;
DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(max);

SET @MyTableName = 'FooTable';


SET @DynamicSQL = N'SELECT * INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@MyTableName) + ' FROM BarTable';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL;
```

Comment: exec @DynamicSQL should be: exec(@DynamicSQL); -- without the parenthesis, throws "name not a valid identifier".

Comment: I have the same result as @plditallo. Without the parenthesis I get error: "Could not find stored procedure..." EXEC without brackets attempts to call a procedure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382753/calling-exec-generates-error-could-not-find-stored-procedure

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you can't use bind variables for table names, column names, etc.  IN this case you must generate dynamic SQL and use `exec`.

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @Script NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Script = N'SELECT * INTO SomeTableName_' + N'20100526' + N' FROM SomeTableName';
EXEC sp_executesql @Script
```

I've left the date separate as I assume you want to calculate it for every run.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into using synonyms:

-- Create a synonym for the Product table in AdventureWorks2008R2.
CREATE SYNONYM MyProduct
FOR AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product;
GO

-- Query the Product table by using the synonym.
USE tempdb;
GO
SELECT ProductID, Name
FROM MyProduct
WHERE ProductID < 5;
GO

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @MyTableName nvarchar(20);
DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(1000);

SET @MyTableName = "FooTable";


SET @DynamicSQL = N'SELECT * INTO ' + @MyTableName + ' FROM BarTable';

exec @DynamicSQL;
```

this query is correct but just use single quote at the ("FooTable")='FooTable'