# What is the proper way to execute Dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have lots of SQL scripts in our codebase, which produce dynamic SQL statements, and we execute these statements against the database with

```
EXEC (@FINALSQL)
```

It is declared like this

```
 DECLARE @FINALSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

In one of our scripts, we now get an error when executing the dynamic SQL:

> Error Number: 2812
> Error Severity: 16
> ErrorState: 62
> ErrorMessage: Could not find stored procedure

with the SQL statement following.

The error number is related to the the error message but still couldn't find any related issue of how to resolve this problem.

I have also read this question but it didn't help because I already enclosed dynamic SQL in brackets
[calling EXEC() generates error: could not find stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382753/calling-exec-generates-error-could-not-find-stored-procedure)

Any ideas what could have caused the problem?

Update: the use of `@FINALSQL` is to create Updates for an amount on tables based on condition in the script.

Comment: The "proper" way is the use a **parameterised** call to `sys.sp_executesql`.

Comment: can you be more specific or can you answer the question in order to mark it as answered @Larnu

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql

Comment: @NickStavrou . . . The error message is probably due to a stored procedure call in the dynamic SQL, not the use of `EXEC`.

Comment: In dynamic sql am not calling any SP definitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to almost anything dynamic can be found in Erland Sommarskog's
tour de force.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

"Execute" is optional for the first statement in a batch when executing a stored procedure. There is likely some formatting error in the string and the parser is trying to interpret the first word as a procedure name after failing to parse it otherwise.

If you have no option to capture the string, then use an Extended Event session or trace to capture the query for errors.

If it was a real procedure, then I 'd suspect that current database is wrong.  A "USE mydatabase;" as the first thing in the string would fix that. But you state this is not the case.  Also, the procedure name was not listed in the error message.

Comment: Yes indeed this post from  Erland Sommarskog has many information. Thanks alot.