# How to create a date parameter into a table name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this parameters in SQL Server:

```sql
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

DECLARE @FECHA_ACT VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @PERIODO  char(6)
SET @FECHA_ACT = CONVERT(CHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)
SET @PERIODO=cast(CONVERT(CHAR(6),GETDATE(),112) as int)
```

I want to create a table using :

```sql
TEMPDB..#abc_def_['+@FECHA_ACT+']
```

but I am getting this error when I tried to create the table:

```
> Database name 'TEMPDB' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.  
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15  
> Incorrect syntax near ''+@FECHA_ACT+''.  
> Database name 'TEMPDB' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.  
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19  
> Incorrect syntax near ''+@FECHA_ACT+'''.  
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 32  
> Incorrect syntax near 'B'.
```

Comment: As the error tells you, you don't reference a temporary table with 3 part naming, just use `#TableName`.

Comment: This, however, smells like an XY Problem; you can't use a variable to replace a literal (in this case the table's name). What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am creating a Temorary table like this:        SELECT *
INTO TEMPDB..#abc_def_['+@FECHA_ACT+'']
FROM ....... I need to create this table weakly, so Every single time I am gonna execute I need to change date of table....example execution today: outcome tempdb..#abc_cdf_20201123 ( I wanted to concatenate date like a parameter) execution next monday  outcome -> tempdb..#abc_cdf_20201130, That I need

Comment: Yes, but *why* do you want to do that at all? As I said, this smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: a quick search will reveail this has been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678725/how-to-set-table-name-in-dynamic-sql-query .

Comment: Note, as well, that a temporary table can only references in the scope (or inner scopes) it was created in, and only persists for the duration of that scope. You would *have* to use a dynamic statement here, meaning that as soon as the dynamic statement ended, your temporary table would be dropped.

Comment: Do you have any example of that??

Comment: *"
Do you have any example of that??"* [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=83be74220e7b69e9e8cfa2048b4f7c98)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a dynamic query.

For example:

```sql
SET DATEFORMAT DMY

DECLARE @FECHA_ACT VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(1000)
SET @FECHA_ACT = CONVERT(CHAR(10),GETDATE(),112)
SET @DynamicSQL = N'CREATE TABLE abc_def_' + @FECHA_ACT + ' (id int)'
EXEC(@DynamicSQL)
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905878/creating-sql-table-using-dynamic-variable-name) for more details.

Comment: This isn't particularly secure mind. `@FECHA_ACT` is only a `varchar(10)` here, fortunately, but longer values would open up a huge injection hole.